# How do I make a dynamic list of items the children of a RecyclerView's items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Inside of my RecyclerView I want to have a dynamic number of items that are children of each item in my RecyclerView. I temporarily made extra layouts and set their visibility to gone and then turn them visible when the add button is pressed, but I know that isn't good practice. I don't think a ListView nested inside of a RecyclerView would be the right thing. If it is, then please enlighten me on how I would go about that. **note:** I can't get the first line of my code to show in the code snippet for some reason

## Exercise Adapter

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseAdapter.ExerciseAdapterViewHolder> {

    private List<Exercise> mExerciseList;
    private static int counter = 0;

    public class ExerciseAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        final TextView anotherSetTextview;
        final LinearLayout linearLayout4;
        final LinearLayout linearLayout5;

        ExerciseAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            anotherSetTextview = view.findViewById(R.id.another_set);
            linearLayout4 = view.findViewById(R.id.layout4);
            linearLayout5 = view.findViewById(R.id.layout5);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExerciseAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.list_item_cardview;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, false);
        return new ExerciseAdapterViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ExerciseAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Exercise currentExercise = mExerciseList.get(position);
        String count = Integer.toString(position + 1) + ".";
        holder.anotherSetTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                if(counter==1)
                    holder.linearLayout4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else if(counter==2)
                    holder.linearLayout5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null == mExerciseList) return 0;
        return mExerciseList.size();
    }

    public void setExerciseData(List<Exercise> exerciseData) {
        mExerciseList = exerciseData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addNewExercise(Exercise e){
        mExerciseList.add(e);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

---

I'm making a workout tracker app for my class and I want the user to add exercises as needed and then they add the sets for each exercise as needed. Basically each Exercise object in the RecyclerView needs to have their own dynamic number of Set objects as the children. This screenshot of what I have so far should help visualize what I'm going for. I'm still new to posting on here, so forgive me for the poor formatting.

[image: What I got so far]

Comment: From what I understood, you want to show a list of exercises (cards) and inside each card you want to have a dynamic list of "sets", right? Have you tried having a recyclerview inside your card view layout?

Comment: @BMacedo That's what I ended up doing. I guess I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

you can inflate the view dynamically in recycler view item. just have a Linear layout in  *R.layout.list_item_cardview* layout, create a the data you want as another *child* layout and inflate the child layouts as you wish.

```
public class ExerciseAdapter 
extendsRecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseAdapter.ExerciseAdapterViewHolder> {

private List<Exercise> mExerciseList;

public class ExerciseAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    final TextView anotherSetTextview;
    final LinearLayout layout;

    ExerciseAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        anotherSetTextview = view.findViewById(R.id.another_set);
        layout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    }
}

@Override
public ExerciseAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
    int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.list_item_cardview;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, false);
    return new ExerciseAdapterViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ExerciseAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Exercise currentExercise = mExerciseList.get(position);

    for(int i=0;i<currentExercise.count;i++)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(holder.itemView.getContext());
        LinearLayout linearLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
        holder.layout.addView(linearLayout);
    }
    holder.anotherSetTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentExercise.count++;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (null == mExerciseList) return 0;
    return mExerciseList.size();
}

public void setExerciseData(List<Exercise> exerciseData) {
    mExerciseList = exerciseData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addNewExercise(Exercise e){
    mExerciseList.add(e);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up going with a nested recyclerview. I guess it wasn't as complicated as I thought it would be.